# On Whitney's paper on real algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, singularity-theory

I had previously asked this question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653716/non-singular-points-of-a-variety) and did not receive an answer and so I decided to reword it and pose it here.

This question is based on Whitney's paper titled "[Elementary Structure of Real Algebraic Varieties](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969908?seq=1)", published in the Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 66, No. 3, November 1957.

At the end of section 7 of the above-mentioned paper, Whitney says that $g$ is analytic on $M^*$ seen as an open connected subset of the $(x_{\rho+1}',...,x_n')$-space. Since $g$ is a polynomial in $x_1,...,x_n$, it would make sense to say that it is analytic in $M^*$ under the usual chart, but why should it continue to be analytic in the open subset of the $(x_{\rho+1}',...,x_n')$-space?

I am also finding it extremely confusing as to which field Whitney is working with (because he mentions that he will be proving "Theorem 1" which uses the above-mentioned result first in the complex case, but then never discusses the base field after), the real or the complex (a clarification on that would greatly help)? So, I shall consider both cases.

**If the field is $\mathbb{C}$:**
In this case, it is easy to solve. If $\phi$ is the defined diffeomorphism from $U$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ to the new chart, then $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are both smooth and so $g\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth from $M^*$ as an open subset of the $(x_{\rho+1},...,x_n)$-space and hence analytic.

**If the field is $\mathbb{R}$:**
In this case, I know that the function $g\circ \phi^{-1}$ as defined above is smooth, but I see no reason for it to be analytic.

The only conclusion I could draw is the following (assume $\mathbb{k}$ is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$):

> If $h_1,...,h_n\in \mathbb{k}[x_1,..,x_n]$ are polynomials such that for some $p\in \mathbb{k}^n$, there exists an open set $U$ containing $p$ such that $h(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{k}^n$ and diffeomorphic to $U$, where $h=(h_1,...,h_n)$, then, if $h^{-1}=(h_1',...,h_n')$ on $h(U)$, then each $h_i'$ is analytic.

**I am not sure if this result is correct**. If it is, then it helps give a unified solution for both, the real and the complex case.

Comment: It would have helped to know that all the undefined objects in the question are actually introduced in your original math.SE question. The chart $\phi$, as defined, is analytic. The inverse function theorem guarantees that $\phi^{-1}$ is also real analytic, not just smooth. This holds both in the real and complex cases. I don't think you need anything else.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine thank you very much. That helps a lot!